# Optimal way to do array intersection in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, malloc, set-intersection

I have a list of sample ID's with each sample possessing certain information in the format `[x]=2, [y]=3, [z]= 4`. I want to write a function which returns the list of sample ID's satisfying certain criteria.

The structure of my query is `[cond1,cond2,...,condn, operator=AND/OR]`. For example if my query is: `[x<5,y==3,x!=2,operator=AND]`, then following is my algorithm to process it,

```
Step 1: Allocate (malloc) 2 array pointers namely arr_final, arr_temp. 
Step 2: Find all the samples with `x<5` store them in array `arr_final`, 
Step 3: Find all the samples with `y==3`, store them in array `arr_temp`. 
Step 4: Find the intersection of arr_final, arr_temp and store the result in `arr_final`.
Step 5: Find all the samples with `x!=2` store them in array `arr_temp`.
Step 6: Repeat step 4
Step 7: Return arr_final
```

If the operator is `OR` then I keep only one array which is `arr_final`, store the sample id's if they are not present in array already and return `arr_final` at the end.

Will be above algorithm work optimally or is there a better one?

Comment: Evaluate the three conditions on each sample as you progress through the source array, writing only the results to the target array.  You are doing many more scans of the arrays with your approach, which can lead to lower performance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The conditions can be more than 3 frequently. What do I do in that case?

Comment: You don't need an `arr_temp`, just evaluate all predicates in single batch on each entry (and use two different implementations for OR and AND) and you are good to go in a single pass. No merge / intersect pass and only a single iteration over the data set for higher data locality.

Comment: Regardless of the number of conditions, evaluate all the conditions on each row as you process it. Knowing the costs of the predicates is an important part of establishing an optimal query plan in a DBMS. Unless there is some phenomenal cost to evaluating the conditions that can be mitigated by not interleaving the queries (for example, if the `y==3` query is efficient only if you never interleave evaluations of that predicate with the evaluation of `x!=2` and vice versa — which is pretty unlikely), filtering all conditions at once will be quicker than multiple passes over the data.